# Optimisation in R using Ucminf package

Tags: r, optimization

I am not able to apply ucminf function to minimise my cost function in R.

Here is my cost function:

```
costfunction <- function(X,y,theta){ 
m <- length(y);
J = 1/m * ((-t(y)%*%log(sigmoid(as.matrix(X)%*%as.matrix(theta))))  - ((1-t(y))%*%log(1-sigmoid(as.matrix(X)%*%as.matrix(theta)))))
}
```

Here is my sigmoid function:

```
sigmoid <- function(t){
g = 1./(1+exp(-t))  
}
```

Here is my gradient function:

```
gradfunction <- function(X,y,theta){ 

grad =  1/ m * t(X) %*% (sigmoid(as.matrix(X) %*% as.matrix(theta) - y));

}
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
library("ucminf")
data <- read.csv("ex2data1.txt",header=FALSE)
X <<- data[,c(1,2)]
y <<- data[,3]
qplot(X[,1],X[,2],colour=factor(y))
m <- dim(X)[1]
n <- dim(X)[2]
X <- cbind(1,X)
initial_theta <<- matrix(0,nrow=n+1,ncol=1)
cost <- costfunction(X,y,initial_theta)
grad <- gradfunction(X,y,initial_theta)
```

This is where I want to call [ucminf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ucminf/ucminf.pdf) to find the minimum cost and values of theta. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Before anything else, I think it is a good idea to remove the calls of `<<-` with regular assignments `<-`. You only need `<<-` when you want to assign to a different than the current environment (as everything you do is in the global environment, the `<<-` doesn't make a lot of sense here). Also, `<<-` is considered potentially dangerous (i.e., unintended consequences).

Comment: Completely agree! Left by mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do the week2 problem of the machine learning course of Coursera.

No need to use `ucminf` packages here, you can simply use the R function `optim` it works

We will define the sigmoid and cost function first.

```
sigmoid <- function(z)
    1 / (1 + exp(-z))


costFunction <- function(theta, X, y) {
    m <- length(y)
    J <- -(1 / m) * crossprod(c(y, 1 - y), 
                    c(log(sigmoid(X %*% theta)), log(1 - sigmoid(X %*% theta))))
    grad <- (1 / m) * crossprod(X, sigmoid(X %*% theta) - y)
    list(J = J, grad = grad)
}
```

Let's load the data now, to make this code it reproductible, I put the data in my dropbox.

```
download.file("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8750577/ex2data1.txt", 
 method = "curl", destfile = "/tmp/ex2data1.txt")

data <- matrix(scan('/tmp/ex2data1.txt', what = double(), sep = ","), 
         ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
X <- data[, 1:2]
y <- data[, 3, drop = FALSE]

m <- nrow(X)
n <- ncol(X)
X <- cbind(1, X)
initial_theta = matrix(0, nrow = n + 1)
```

We can then compute the result of the cost function at the initial theta like this

```
cost <- costFunction(initial_theta, X, y)

(grad <- cost$grad)
##         [,1]
## [1,]  -0.100
## [2,] -12.009
## [3,] -11.263


(cost <- cost$J)
##         [,1]
## [1,] 0.69315
```

Finally we can use `optim` to ge the optimal theta

```
res <- optim(par = initial_theta, 
             fn = function(t) costFunction(t, X, y)$J,
             gr = function(t) costFunction(t, X, y)$grad,
             method = "BFGS", control = list(maxit = 400))

(theta <- res$par)
##           [,1]
## [1,] -25.08949
## [2,]   0.20566
## [3,]   0.20089


(cost <- res$value)
## [1] 0.2035
```

If you have some problem with the function `download.file`, the data can be downloaded
[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8750577/ex2data1.txt)

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it is hard to exactly give you the code you need, but the general idea is to hand the functions over to `ucminf`:

```
ucminf(start, costfunction, gradfunction, y = y, theta = initial_theta)
```

Note that `start` needs to be a vector of initial starting values which when handed over as `X` to the two functions need to produce a result. Usually you use random starting value (e.g., `runif`).